# A convex optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

Assume that $R(k_1,k_2)$ is a $3 \times 3$ positive definite matrix for $k_1 = 0,1,k_2 =0,1$, $L(k_1,k_2)$ is a $3 \times 1$ vector for $k_1 = 0,1,k_2 =0,1$, $z$ is a scalar, and $\alpha_i(k) \in (0,1)$ for $i=1,2$, $k=0,1$. We want to find x and functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ that solve the following optimization problem:

\begin{align}
\min_{x, f_1, f_2} \sum_{y_1 \in \{0,1\}} \sum_{y_2 \in \{0,1\}} \alpha_1(y_1) \alpha_2(y_2) \Big(
\begin{bmatrix} x &f_1(y_1) & f_2(y_2) \end{bmatrix} R(y_1,y_2)
\begin{bmatrix} x \\f_1(y_1) \\ f_2(y_2) \end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} x &f_1(y_1) & f_2(y_2) \end{bmatrix} L(y_1,y_2) z
\Big).
\end{align}

The minimizer $x$, $f_1$, and $f_2$ should be based on parameter $z$. Any idea for solving this problem?

The function we are optimizing over is the sum of four functions each of them is strictly convex. So, the sum of them is also strictly convex. If we define $s_1^0 = f_1(0)$, $s_1^1 = f_1(1)$, $s_2^0 = f_2(0)$, and $s_2^1 = f_2(1)$. Then we can write the optimization problem as optimizing over $x,s_1^0,s_1^1, s_2^0, s_2^1$ as follows which is a optimization over a strictly convex function of $x,s_1^0,s_1^1, s_2^0, s_2^1$. Right?

\begin{align}
\min_{x,s_1^0,s_1^1, s_2^0, s_2^1} \Bigg[
&\alpha_1(0) \alpha_2(0) \Big(
\begin{bmatrix} x &s_1^0 & s_2^0 \end{bmatrix} R(0,0)
\begin{bmatrix} x \\s_1^0 \\ s_2^0 \end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} x &s_1^0 & s_2^0 \end{bmatrix} L(0,0) z
\Big) \\
+
&\alpha_1(0) \alpha_2(1) \Big(
\begin{bmatrix} x &s_1^0 & s_2^1 \end{bmatrix} R(0,1)
\begin{bmatrix} x \\s_1^0 \\ s_2^1 \end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} x &s_1^0 & s_2^1 \end{bmatrix} L(0,1) z
\Big) \\
+
&\alpha_1(1) \alpha_2(0) \Big(
\begin{bmatrix} x &s_1^1 & s_2^0 \end{bmatrix} R(1,0)
\begin{bmatrix} x \\s_1^1 \\ s_2^0 \end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} x &s_1^1 & s_2^0 \end{bmatrix} L(1,0) z
\Big) \\
+
&\alpha_1(1) \alpha_2(1) \Big(
\begin{bmatrix} x &s_1^1 & s_2^1 \end{bmatrix} R(1,1)
\begin{bmatrix} x \\s_1^1 \\ s_2^1 \end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} x &s_1^1 & s_2^1 \end{bmatrix} L(1,1) z
\Big) \Bigg]
\end{align}

This optimization can be written as

\begin{align}
\min_{x,s_1^0,s_1^1, s_2^0, s_2^1} \Big(
\begin{bmatrix} x &s_1^0 &s_1^1 &s_2^0 &s_2^1 \end{bmatrix} Q
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ s_1^0 \\ s_1^1 \\ s_2^0 \\ s_2^1 \end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} x &s_1^0 &s_1^1 &s_2^0 &s_2^1 \end{bmatrix} P z
\Big)
\end{align}
where $Q$ is a $5 \times 5$ matrix and $P$ is a $5 \times 1$ vector. Since the second optimizing optimization problem is a strictly convex function of $x,s_1^0,s_1^1, s_2^0, s_2^1$, this one should also be. Right? Does this mean that $Q$ is PD and invertible?

Comment: @OGC I added my idea to the question. I think that idea may work, but I wanted to know whether it works or there is any better approach?

Comment: Just assemble Q and check its eigenvalues.

Comment: Even if Q isn't positive semidefinite, it's an unconstrained quadratic, and can therefore be solved analytically.

Comment: @MichaelGrant My problem is not numerical. I know that $R(\cdot,\cdot)$'s are PD, and $\alpha$'s belong to $(0,1)$. So, based on this I want to know whether $Q$ is PD.

Comment: @MichaelGrant How can we solve a quadratic optimization problem when we don't know whether $Q$ is positive definite? If $Q$ is not PD (PSD) nor ND (NSD), then it may have lots of local mins and maxs.

Comment: @MichaelGrant can you take a look at the edited problem?